# How can I manipulate a form / inputs to be ignored when a form is submitted

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors, expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine and SafeCracker along with Ajax (plugin: jquery.form.js - http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Best I can tell, SafeCracker will only allow for updating a single entry at a time. However, the UI / UX necessitates that a list be displayed. I've proof of concept'ed an entry by entry on-demand form. That is, click a particular edit link next to each entry and a snippet of jquery creates a form along with displaying a submit button. Click submit and that single entry updates. The inputs don't exist until the Update link is clicked

What I would prefer to do, if possible, is to create the non-form and form versions of each entry as the page is renbered and use some sort of toggle to display one or the other. Again, doable. Then, when I click the Edit link I'd add the necessary attributes to the input so that entry's form elements will be read but the other (display: none) elements for the other entries will be ignored. I'm thinking (out loud) that if I add the attr("name", some-value) that would work. That is, an input with no name will be ignored.

Yes, I can test this and I will. However, even if it works I'm not sure if it's a best practice and/or there's a more ideal way of accomplishing my ends. I'm here looking for validation and/or additional expertise and input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set `disabled` property to inputs and they will excluded from ***Form submission***, whatever input fields are `hidden` or `visible`. Different jQuery methods, like `submit()` and `serialize()` follow specification of HTML 4 and exclude all disabled controls of a forms. So one way is to set

```
$('your_input').prop('disabled', true);
```

or ,

```
$('your_input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

**Check following link:**

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Also, you may use a general `button` instead of a `submit`, as result you can handle click event on it and within that event you can make exclusion, validation, manipulation on values and what ever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details on the linky. Big big help.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `disabled` attribute on them server side or set the property via jQuery:

```
$(".hidden input").prop("disabled", true);
```